# Django ORM returns non-iterable object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

The model is

```
class WeeklyStrMst(BaseModel):
    StoreId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    TDLinx_No = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Week = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Week_Number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    SeasonalPackaging = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Consumption = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    PackType = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    Volume = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    POS = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    StoreName = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    MasterChain = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    TerritoryName = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    RegionName = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    StoreClassification = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    StateName = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = config_data[settings.REGION_NAME]['tables']['weekly_mstr']
```

`WeeklyStrMst.objects.filter(StoreId__in=stores).values()`

Here stores is of list datatype containing 6000-30000 values which are non-null, integer, so when I execute this, it returns me -

```
<django.db.models.query.QuerySet object at 0x0000024FD4EAAAF0>
```

I have tested with less than 2000 values it works fine. What could be possible reason and workaround for this scenario?
How to pass a large list of array as a filter criteria?

Comment: Please don't provide the code as a screenshot; instead, edit your post so that the code is in text format. Also, be sure that you're providing enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide your code for the model that you've created.

Comment: Please *don't* use `.values()`: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: @Shayan the model is now available, thanks for the warm welcome.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I require specific values like

values('Year', 'Week', 'StoreClassification', 'StoreId', 'StoreName', 'MasterChain', 'TerritoryName', 'RegionName')
This is the reason I have added

Comment: @DebadattaBhattacharjee: then you use `.only(..)`, not `.values(..)`: this is a *primitive obsession antipattern*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, sure will change, this helps, thank you. Meanwhile any idea why I cannot pass more than 2000 values in stores for .filter(StoreId__in=stores)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I had to update the library mssql-django, the earlier version had limit on the number of parameters that can be passed, which they have updated.

Answer (score 1):

The [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/) class **is** iterable - you can use it inside any `for` loop ([even in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)).

The [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) function returns a QuerySet of dictionaries instead of your model instances and is, rest assured, also an iterable.

**Edit** -

If you're using SQLite for your database, there is usually a limit set on how many values you can pass for `IN` queries - https://sqlite.org/limits.html. You can change this value depending on the system you're using. Besides, if you're dealing with extremely heavy datasets, you'd be better off with a more scalable database like Postgres or MySQL.

Comment: I understand your point, but if the coditions dont match your criteria, it simply returns empty queryset, but when I pass more than 2000 values in ->stores;

 Stores__in=stores

It gives me -> <django.db.models.query.QuerySet object at 0x0000024FD4EAAAF0>

Which is non iterable

Comment: Hi, I just updated the answer - turns out it's to do with a hard limit of usual 999 or 2000 value set by SQLite (which I'm assuming is what you're using) for use in `IN` queries. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes correct, is there any way to bypass that? Or any workaround?

Comment: I am using MS Sql Server and I could not get anything